# Solve equations with condition on variable to reduce the number of solutions

Tags: equation-solving

I'm trying to solve an equation, and while it work, "plain" `Solve` returns two solutions that are, in the specific case, of no interest.

```
Clear[r, h, V]
V[r_, h_] := \[Pi] r^2 h
A[r_, h_] := \[Pi] r^2 + 2 \[Pi] r h
h0 = h /. Solve[V[r, h] == V0, h][[1]]
D[A[r, h0], r]
Solve[D[A[r, h0], r] == 0, r]
```

So I tried, as suggested on some web pages,

```
Solve[D[A[r, h0], r] == 0 && r > 0, r]
```

but `Mathematica` returns `{}`.

What is the correct syntax to get the correct solution? TIA.

(N.B.: Though probably not important for the question, the mathematical problem above is about how to find the radius $r$ and height $h$ for a circular cylinder with a bottom (no top) that consumes the least material given a volume $V_0$.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the information that `v0 > 0`:

```
Solve[D[A[r, h0], r] == 0 && r > 0 && V0 > 0, r][[1]]
```

> {r -> ConditionalExpression[Root[-V0 + π #1^3 &, 1], V0 > 0]}

Or specify the domain as `PositiveReals`:

```
Solve[D[A[r, h0], r] == 0, r, PositiveReals][[1]]
```

> {r -> ConditionalExpression[Root[-V0 + π #1^3 &, 1], V0 > 0]}

```
 FullSimplify[%, V0 > 0]
```

> {r -> V0^(1/3)/π^(1/3)}

Comment: Thanks! To get the $r$ assigned to a variable $r_0$ I wrote `r0 = r /. FullSimplify[%, V0 > 0][[1]]`. Is there some 'shorter' syntax to 'extract' the only value when the (double) output list is one item only so I don't have to type `[[1]]`? Trying to understand the `FullSimply`; why do I have to specify `V0>0` again since it was given in the `Solve` command and also in the `ConditionalExpression` command?

Comment: @mf67, in don't know of any way to avoid using `[[1]]`  (you can put after `Solve` or after `FullSimplify`).  `ConditionalExpresssion` does not eliminate the condition `V0>0`; so wee need to use `FullSimplify` using the same condition again.

Answer (score 2):

From a mathematical point of view this type of problem is sometimes more easily solved using Lagrange multipliers for the constraints,

```
V[r_, h_] := \[Pi] r^2 h
A[r_, h_] := \[Pi] r^2 + 2 \[Pi] r h + \[Lambda] (V[r, h] - V0)

solns = Solve[{D[A[r, h], r] == 0, D[A[r, h], h] == 0, D[A[r, h], \[Lambda]] == 0}, {r, h, \[Lambda]}] 

soln = Map[Reduce[Join[#, {r > 0, h > 0, V0 > 0}]] &, solns /. Rule -> Equal]

Cases[soln, Except[False]]

(* {V0 > 0 && \[Lambda] == (-2*Pi^(1/3))/V0^(1/3) && r == V0^(1/3)/Pi^(1/3) && h == V0^(1/3)/Pi^(1/3)} *)
```

Comment: That is interesting. The 4th line is however, for me, difficult to understand and I have not (yet) found a good tutorial for all these 'cryptic' commands that are very powerful, once you know them.

Comment: To understand line 4, just pull it apart the same way it got put together: Evaluate `solns /. Rule -> Equal`, see what it does. Take out the `Reduce[]`, evaluate and see what that does. If you don't know `Map`, see what `Map[f, solns/.Rule->Equal]` does. Finally, look up the documentation for `Function` (which will explain `#` and `&`).